# Trying to print Strings from an array but its only printing null

Tags: java, null

I have one class that creates a deck of cards. Here is the code:
public class Cards

```
public class Cards
{
    int Suit;
    int Card;
    int sizeOfHand = 5;
    int numPlayers = 5; //determined by user
    String[] suits = {"diamonds", "clubs", "hearts", "spades"};

    String[] values = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
    boolean[][] chosen;
    String[] deck = new String[52];
    boolean done = false;

    public void card()
    {
    while(!done)
    {
        chosen = new boolean[13][4];

        for(int j = 0; j < 52; j++)
        {
            do
            {
                Suit = (int)(Math.random() * suits.length);
                Card = (int)(Math.random() * values.length);
            }
            while(chosen[Card][Suit]);

            chosen[Card][Suit] = true; //makes sure card is not picked twice

            deck[j] = values[Card] + suits[Suit]; //sets each of the 52 values of deck to a "card"

            done = true; //if it has picked every card
        }
    }
}
}
```

And another class that should give a "player" 8 of these cards, here is the code for that:

```
public class Player
{   
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String name;
    int balance;
    boolean cont = true;

    String[] hand = new String[8];

    Cards c = new Cards();

    //set i = to what ever number player you are on
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        hand[i] = c.deck[i];
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hand));
    }
}
```

When I try and print the players hand it prints; [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null] instead of the actual cards the player has. Anyone know why this happens?

Comment: What makes you think there shouldn't be nulls in your array? Which part of your code should ensure it?

Comment: There is no part that does that, how would i do that?

Comment: You should call `c.card()` before you print.

Comment: You are printing `Arrays.toString(hand)` which result in `[null, .. , null]`. Since you posted this question I am assuming you believe there should be printed other values than `null`. Your assumption is probably based on earlier assigning `hand[i] = c.deck[i];` in a loop, but based on printed results we can assume that `c.deck[i]` also holds `null`. Which part of your code is responsible for filling that `c.deck[i]` with cards? Is it some method (like `card()`)? Did you call that method somewhere (directly or indirectly) earlier before executing `hand[i] = c.deck[i];`?

Comment: doing the c.card() did the trick! thanks guys!

Comment: Please read ["How to debug small programs"](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Or change public void card() to public Cards()